# Has anybody had issues installing AEHD in Android Studio (Giraffe) to replace the deprecated HAXM?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

Our IT Support Department are unhappy running deprecated software. Intel HAXM has been deprecated and is no longer supported. Having problems installing AEHD.

Their tentative solution is to airgap the development machines or stick them on a VLAN :(

I've tried to install AEHD which is now supposed to support Intel processors but it keeps failing.  Tried with Admin privileges and also logged in as local admin.  Log file isn't helpful. I did uninstall HAXM first.

Has anybody successfully managed this?

Win 10 Enterprise 22H2 Build 19045_3448, Dell Precision 7560

Btw, anybody managed to get an emulator running with HAXM 7.8.0?  I can only get it to work with 7.7.1. Android Studio SDK Manager still wants to install 7.6.5 which has a CVE against it (privileges escalation) which is a huge no no for them.

Thanks in advance.

Jim W

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out night before last and this [GitHub answer](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver/issues/10#issuecomment-696832752) did the trick for me. I did have to uninstall and reinstall through Android Studio after running through those instructions for it to pick up the changes.

Comment: Hi Shane,
Thanks for the post.
Are you running an Intel or AMD processor?
The GitHub link was very long and seemed to be related to AMD only.
Which bit worked for you?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jim, no worries. It may take a bit to load but the link should go to the comment made by bonellia on Sep 22, 2020. I ran through those steps and it worked for me, running Intel.

Comment: Hi Shane, had a chat with our IT Support.  I'm slightly concerned about some of the subsequent posts in that GitHub thread.  Arranging to trial it on a sacrificial laptop which can be easily reimaged rather than a production machine.  Will update when I've done that.